# How to handle date binding in Nancy?

Tags: nancy

Upgrading from Nancy 1 to Nancy 2 I am facing a problem with binding date parameters. I am sending the following json payload from an angularjs app:
{
   date=2018-04-30T22:00:00.000Z
}

When binding the object with Nancy 2 it is converted to 30.04.2018 22:00:00. and not to 01.05.2018 00:00:00. How do I convert to the local (Croatian) time zone?

Comment: The `Z` suffix marks the DateTime as UTC. Why do you expect it to convert to a local time?

Comment: It's just that the code didn't change when upgrading from Nancy 1 to Nancy 2. Worked beforehand.